# How to manage global variables

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, variables, global-variables

I know this is very basic thing but i need to know that how can i declare / assign value / use global variables.

because i have already declared variable global here it is :

[image]

now i am adding value which is geeting from server response like

[image]

now in console i am getting output in that global variable.

[image]

now, my problem is when i use that global variables values as param value to call API it will take ZERO. not getting correct value

[image]

Thanks for guide

Comment: Its seems you assign a value to the local variable, not global variable after getting data from a server, just remove var keyword from the local variable where you assign values.

Comment: when i remove var give error : Cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: Are you wanting the 'global' variables to exist beyond the view controller itself?

Comment: yes i am adding value in global variable when server give me response after that response value use and store in to global variable and then after that global variable value need to use further got me ?

Comment: Please add here your JSON response

Comment: You should really try to avoid using globals like this at all.  Perhaps look into using a singleton class or a much more structured data model.

Comment: @Nilesh SUCCESS: {
    userResult =     (
                {
            "request_id" = 0d1b96922e414306965d1dd9cc5ad8ac;
            "user_id" = 105;
        }
    );
}

Comment: @Nilesh above is my JSON response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove **var** keyword from the local variable where you assign values and add below code instead.

```
global_userid = ["\(oDict["userResult"][0]["user_id"])"]
global_reqid = ["\(oDict["userResult"][0]["request_id"])"]
```

Comment: bro u r very close it will take user_id but not taking valid request_id